# Overriding Array toString in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to override the `toString` without explicitly instantiating an object with `new`.

See following example:

```
class SemicolonArray extends Array {
  public toString() {
    return this.join(';');
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(arr: SemicolonArray) {
    this.arr = arr;
  }
  arr: SemicolonArray;
}

const foo = new Foo([1,2,3]);
console.log(foo.arr.toString());  // "1,2,3"
```

I would however expect `"1;2;3"`. Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

Edit:

To clarify further, I would like to do this:

```
interface Bar {
  hello :string

  bar() : string
}

class Foo implements Bar {
  hello: string
  bar() {
    return this.hello;
  }
}

const foo = { hello: 'hello' } as Foo
foo.bar()
```

However `bar` is not a method. Is there a way to make sure that every object casted as Foo has the bar method?

Comment: `foo.arr` _isn't_ a `SemicolonArray`, you didn't create one anywhere.

Comment: You can modify the global prototype: `Array.prototype.toString = function() { return this.join(';'); }`. This will apply to _all_ arrays. But this technique is **strongly discouraged** in most contexts because it can cause all sorts of compatibility breakages.

Comment: My preferred design would be to create a global `function toSemicolonString(array) { return array.join(';'); }`.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas in that a global function is probably the cleanest solution for a simple `.join(';')`. If you had more methods (preferably with distinct names, so typescript can decide between your array type and a normal array), then a class may be the cleaner solution.

Comment: @Thomas I'm really looking to override the toString method as it will be passed as value to an <input> and there needs to be formatted as semicolon seperated values

Comment: That sounds like a UI concern, which should not be coded like that in your data structure itself. Just do the join explicitly at the place where the value is assigned to the `<input>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct issues here:

1. Making array literal syntax create a `SemicolonArray`.
2. `Foo` is expecting a `SemicolonArray` but TypeScript doesn't complain when you pass in a base array instead, since the shape of a base array matches the shape of a `SemicolonArry`.

#### Making array literal create subclass

There's no way to make an array literal create an instance of an array subclass. Literal notation cannot be overridden. An array literal can *only* create a standard array.

You could use `SemicolonArray.from`:

```
const foo = new Foo(SemicolonArray.from([1,2,3]));
```

...but `new SemicolonArray(1, 2, 3)` is probably simpler.

Or you could have `Foo` convert a base array to a `SemicolonArray`:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(arr: SemicolonArray) {
        this.arr = arr instanceof SemicolonArray ? arr : SemicolonArray.from(arr);
    }
    arr: SemicolonArray;
}
// ...
const foo = new Foo([1, 2, 3]);
```

#### No error when passing base array

As you've discovered, with your current definition of `SemicolonArray`, TypeScript won't complain about a base array being used instead, since `SemicolonArray` doesn't define any non-method properties. That's because TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shape of types; what properties they have and their types), not *nominal* (based on the name [identity] of types).

That's likely to lead to errors. You can solve it by adding a branding property to `SemicolonArray`:

```
class SemicolonArray extends Array {
    readonly __type__ = "SemicolonArray"; // ***
    public toString() {
        return this.join(";");
    }
}
```

Now, TypeScript won't allow a base array where a `SemicolonArray` is expected.

---

As always with array subclasses, **beware** that the `Array` constructor handles its arguments very idiosyncratically. Your subclass is fine because it doesn't define its own constructor, but if you end up adding one, be sure to handle the complexity.

---

Re your edit:

> However `bar` is not a method. Is there a way to make sure that every object casted as `Foo` has the `bar` method?

No. In fact, TypeScript doesn't have casting at all. It has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). People sometimes use the term "cast" but it's inaccurate. In a language with casting, a cast can actually transform a value (it doesn't necessarily, but it can). For instance, consider this C code:

```
double a = 2.4;
int b = (int)a;
printf("%d\n", b); // 2
```

The cast operation `(int)` actually transforms the value: the operand is `a`, which is of type `double`, but the result of the cast operation is an `int`. The bit pattern of the value is actually transformed at runtime from a `double` bit pattern to an `int` bit pattern, using a conversion process.

Type assertions don't do that. They have no runtime aspect at all, they completely disappear. All that a type assertion does is tell TypeScript that you're sure that the operand is actually a valid instance of the type. The value is still what it was, the **only** thing that's changed is TypeScript's understanding of what type it is.

If you want to convert something to something else, a type assertion doesn't do it. You have to use a conversion of some kind (like `SemicolonArray.from`) that actually produces a new thing of the correct type.

(For the avoidance of doubt: JavaScript has a fair bit of built-in conversion, such as when you do `"42" / 2` or `"x" + 2`. But *TypeScript* doesn't, other than the things it inherits from JavaScript [like those conversions].)

Comment: The main question, namely, whether I can override a method without explictly instantiating an object remains unsolved

Comment: @JeremyKnees - I don't understand what you mean.`[1, 2, 3]` is directly instantiating an object. You said "without `new`" and I answered that: you can't create an instance of `SemicolonArray` without `new` (or something that's basically the same, such as `Reflect.construct`) or `from` or similar. More specifically, you can't do it with literal syntax. Can you clarify what you mean, if that isn't it?

Comment: See my edit. I would expect that everything casted as a certain class has the methods of that class.

Comment: @JeremyKnees - Ah, I understand now. I've added to the end of the answer. The short version is "no," I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: "No. In fact, TypeScript doesn't have casting at all. It has type assertions." Exactly what I was looking for! It's very unfortunate that TS doesn't support this though ...